# How to retrieve WCF service link in flex using httpservices

Tags: web-services, apache-flex, wsdl, flash-builder, httpservice

I want to retrieve server content which is like wsdl link(WCF service URL)using FLEX 4.5.. I haven't worked with webservices on FLEX. I have worked with xml data retrieval using httpservices where I had a local xml datas. Right now, i am trying to retrieve a server content. I have provided with the service link, method name and xml tags. (seems like parameters).. Since this is the first time im trying the server content, I need some help. Your help is highly appreciated.. thanks in advance... Would be better if i can get a sample project on webservices.

This is what I'm trying. The service link is below.
http://mfsapi.blisslogix.net/RSS_FEEDS_SERVICE.svc
When I click on this link, i'm getting the below link.
http://mfsapi.blisslogix.net/RSS_FEEDS_SERVICE.svc?wsdl

where I can see a lot of tags.

I am using HTTPSERVICES and WEBSERVICES to work on this issue and i'm not getting the xml data. I guess I did some mistake on passing the parameters. Please walk me through the steps how can I pass the method and parameters with this link..

Answer (score 0):

First you need to create a `WebService` tag. Or use ActionScript an object of type `WebService`.

```
<mx:WebService id="myWebService"
                   useProxy="false"
                   showBusyCursor="true"
                   load="OnServiceLoad(event)"
                   fault="OnFault(event)">      
        <s:operation name="GetInformation" result="onLoad(event)" fault="onFault(event)">           
        </s:operation>
</mx:WebService>
```

Then you need to specify the WSDL document location and load it.

```
myWebService.loadWSDL("http://mfsapi.blisslogix.net/RSS_FEEDS_SERVICE.svc?wsdl");
```

Then you can simply call the operations specified in the `WebService` tag.

```
myWebService.GetInformation();
```

Here is a [link](http://blogs.4point.com/brad.white/2008/12/4-ways-to-invoke-a-webservice-in-flex-with-mxml-and-actionscript.html) on how to communicate with web services using MXML and AS.